# diferent behaviour in different environments for uninitialised malloced memory

Tags: c, arrays, char, malloc

I was implementing a program related to the use of dynamic allocation in C.
Testing the same piece of code on Visual Studio 2017 and on other IDEs (Dev C ++, Codeblocks, etc.) I have different behaviors:

```
size_t newDim = 9;
char *p = malloc((newDim + 1) * sizeof(char));
p[newDim] = '\0';
printf("%d\n", strlen(p));
```

The output of printf() on Visual studio is: `9`
other IDEs: `3` sometimes `4`.
But when I fill the array with dim-1 characters, the same printf() produces a correct output on the other IDEs. I think that the different compilers have a different way of managing the allocated memory, could someone explain the problem in more detail?
Thank you

Comment: you need `calloc` if you need zero-init. And if you think it's zero, why nul-terminating?

Comment: Should be completely random, but at most 9, because you have not put anything into the memory you allocated, so it's contents are undetermined.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker but why Visual studio behaves in a different why compared to the other compilers? 
So should I initialize the memory, add the terminating zero and then use the strlen () function?

Comment: @arst3k What are you even trying to do here? What is the point to measure an uninitialized string?

Comment: Contents of memory from malloc() is *undefined*. There's no reason to think it should be the same from one compiler to the next, or even one run to the next on the same machine. Malloc just grabs whatever memory is available and assigns it to you. Whatever it might have had in it from previous use is still there. Why would C bother putting anything into it? That's just a waste of time.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Well, `calloc` is doing it.

Comment: Calloc is *defined* to do it. That's its job.

Comment: *The output of printf() on Visual studio is: `9`*  Change from debug to release (or the other way - or any other version of the MSVC run time library that you have available) and see what happens...

Comment: `char *p = malloc((newDim + 1) * sizeof(char));` --> `char *p = calloc(newDim + 1u, sizeof *p);` and let `calloc()` set all to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`malloc` is not initializing the memory allocated, so the allocated space might have zeros in arbitrary places giving different string lengths.

Comment: I had not thought about it ... thank you!